# How does lme4 optimize the variance parameters of random effects (theta vector)?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, optimization

In mixed-effects models within the `lmer` R function of `lme4` calculating the vector $\theta$ seems to be a key step, necessary to obtain the matrix $\Sigma(\theta)$, which is later decomposed as $\Sigma = TSST'$.

The parameter vector $\theta$ is defined as "random-effects parameters estimates; these are parameterized as the relative Cholesky factors of each random effect term".

They are generated through iteration, and get incorporated into the $\Sigma(\theta)$ matrix as in the following example:

In the `sleepstudy` dataset in `lme4` the 'Reaction' time in miliseconds depends on the number of days of sleep deprivation, and the random effect of the actual individual being tested or "Subject."

Fitting a probably nonsensical mixed-effects model as `fit <- lmer(Reaction ~ 1 + (1 | Subject), sleepstudy)` would result in the following T, S and $\Sigma$ matrices in relation to $\theta$:

First off, let's call $\theta$ with `getME(fit,"theta") # 0.807831`. From it we can calculate manually,

`str(sleepstudy$Subject) # Factor w/ 18 levels`

Hence,
`T <- diag(1,18)`.

`S <- T * 0.807831`, and finally `Sigma <- Sigma <- S %*% t(S)`.

It is clear, then, that $\theta$ is key in the `lmer` function. It also sounds as though there is no algebraic formula for it. So the question is, **How do you get $\theta$** **in a step-by-step, easy to follow sequence of operations?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parameterizing variance-covariance matrices is actually rather challenging; in principle an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix can be described by $n(n+1)/2$ parameters, but the need for the matrix to be [positive (semi)definite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix), and the desire to use a parameterization that is convenient for nonlinear optimization (e.g. parameters are not highly correlated with each other, possibly unconstrained, or at worst constrained in a simple way -- see e.g. [Pinheiro and Bates 1996](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00140873)).

In the parameterization that `lme4` uses, the $\theta$ vector represents the (columnwise unpacking of) the lower triangle of the Cholesky factor of the variance-covariance matrix $\Sigma$: for example, in the 2 $\times$ 2 random-slopes case we have
$$
\Sigma = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\theta_1 & 0 \\
\theta_2 & \theta_3 
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\theta_1 & \theta_2 \\
0 & \theta_3 
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\theta_1^2 & \theta_1 \theta_2 \\
\theta_1 \theta_2 & \theta_2^2 + \theta_3^2 
\end{array}
\right) = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\sigma_1^2 & \sigma_{12} \\
\sigma_{12} & \sigma_2^2 
\end{array}
\right)
$$

So in this case, for example, we can equate $\theta_1$ with $\sigma_1$ (the standard deviation of the intercept), $\theta_2$ with $\sigma_{12}/\sigma_1$ (the covariance scaled by the SD) ... $\theta_3$ is a little more complicated.  If there is more than one RE term, the $\theta$ vector is the *concatenation* of the Cholesky factors for each term; in particular, in a model with only random-intercept terms, the $\theta$ vector is just the vector of RE standard deviations.

You're absolutely right that there is no formula -- not even a simple iterative process -- for determining $\theta$.  The way `lme4` works is that, *given* a value of $\theta$, we can determine $\Sigma$ and hence the likelihood

$$
\cal L(\theta) = \int L(y|\boldsymbol b,\boldsymbol \beta) L(\boldsymbol b|\Sigma(\theta)) \, d \boldsymbol b
$$

As described in the [lme4 paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.5823), we can use some fairly clever algebra to reduce the integral above to a calculation that can be done in a few steps of linear algebra; hence, we can fairly efficiently compute the (negative log-)likelihood for a specified value of $\theta$.

After that we have to use brute force (i.e. nonlinear optimization); we pick a starting value for $\theta$ (typically 1 for the diagonal elements and 0 for the off-diagonal elements, which corresponds to starting the *relative* variance-covariance matrix [i.e. the variance-covariance matrix of the random effects scaled by the residual variance] as an identity matrix). Then we use some derivative-free algorithm, typically the [Nelder-Mead simplex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method) or [Powell's BOBYQA algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOBYQA), to adjust the value of $\theta$ until we think we've found a maximum-likelihood solution.

Comment: Does theta carry any tangible probabilistic significance? Does it have an intuitive meaning? Does it stand for a prior?

Comment: This is arguably a separate question, but I'll edit ...

Comment: I'll be happy to enter it as different question. I just have problems "demonstrating" that I did my research, because I truly don't get this concept.